# How do I integrate my R graph/file into Java's Swing?

Tags: java, r, swing

I used JSwing to make a pretty looking GUI that lets me enter some information, that when I hit a button, adds that information to a .csv file.

I have an R file that converts said .csv file into a pretty pi chart to look at, with labels and the like. The goal is to get the graph I made in R to show up in my GUI in its own little box or section. I'd like to note that the graph is meant to be dynamic, changing if I add information, so I can't just grab a picture of the graph and save it.

Is there a java library of some kind that lets me literally import my R file into my JSwing app or something similar? Maybe an R interpreter or something where I copy paste my code from R into some weird object's method or something, similar to how some libraries allow you to straight up type an SQL statement and pass it. Anything that actually gets the job done will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [FastR](https://github.com/oracle/fastr). Following example may be exactly what you are looking for: https://github.com/graalvm/examples/tree/master/fastr_javaui

[image: Java UI with R plot]